# Get arraylist 10 items from some position

Tags: java, arraylist

such a problem, there are 100 positions in the list, I only get the position, and from this position I want to receive the following 10 items.For example, I get 30 and I want to return positions 30-40

I tried `sublist(30,30+10)` but when it comes to the end, an error.

```
ArrayList<Model> numList = new ArrayList<>();
```

in numList i have 100 items;

```
ArrayList<Model> numList2 = new ArrayList<>();
```

in numlist2 i want to be from 30 to 40, but I have only a starting position of 30 and the size that I need is 10.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: @Ioannis Barakos i can`t do it)

Comment: what should happen when list has 30 items and you got the number 25, so starting from 25 +10 =  35, now you don't have the extra 5 numbers after 30 so from where you will get that? in this case it should return 5 numbers of what? or it should start over again from 1 ?

Comment: What is the problem with having 100 items in the list and create a new sublist(30,40). This should work

Comment: params.startPosition and params.loadSize, there i get position and size. For now i have list with 100 items, and position i get 10,20,30 etc. when i get 10 i need 10-20, when 20 - 20-30 etc

Comment: @ Ioannis Barakos i dont know second number, just 30

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList(int,int)) always is informative.

```
List<Model> numList2 = numList.subList(30, 40); // 40 exclusive
```

numList2 is backed by numList in both directions:

```
 numList2.set(0, ...); // numList.get(30) changed
 numList.set(31, ...); // num2List.get(1) changed
```

Independent list:

```
List<Model> numList2 = new ArrayList(numList.subList(30, 40));
```

---

```
List<Model> get10(List<Model> numList, int i) {
    if (i >= numList.size()) {
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
    int i2 = Math.min(i + 10, numList.size());
    return new ArrayList(numList.subList(i, i2));
}
```

Comment: i dont know  second number, i just have 30 and all, and i know that i need 10 items

Answer (score -1):

Here is some approach you can try.. Just Replace your class with Integer from below code.

```
ArrayList<Integer> numList = new ArrayList<>(); //Replace Integer with your class

IntStream.range(1, 101).forEach(v -> numList.add(v)); //Filled out data

ArrayList<Integer> numList2 = numList.subList(30, 30 + 10); //Print 30 to 40
numList2 .forEach(val -> {
    System.out.println("data: " + val);
});;
```

Answer (score -1):

> **public List subList(int fromIndex,int toIndex)**

You can use the above method.

ArrayList numList2 = new ArrayList(numList.subList(30, 40));

```
    if(toIndex<=numList .size()) {
        retutn numListsubList(fromIndex, toIndex);
    }else {
        return new ArrayList<Model>();
    }
```

where fromIndex and toIndex are variables and can be passed as per your requirement.

Comment: i dont know second number, i just have 30 and all, and i know that i need 10 items

Comment: ArrayList numList2 = new ArrayList(numList.subList(30, 30+10)); or ArrayList numList2 = new ArrayList(numList.subList(30, 30+20));// in case required 20 lelements. fromIndex and toIndex in subList(int fromIndex,int toIndex) method are variables and you can pass these parameters as per your requirement.

Comment: when i reach to end, an error will be, couse list have 100 items, i try to find 100+10

Comment: In that case you must check for the list size. i.e if toIndex>numList.size() you should not directly add 10 into toIndex. You should perform this operation only if toIndex<=numList.size()